# How do I keep the split token in the second part of what was split in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, split

In Ruby, how do you split a stirng and keep the token with which you are splitting on in the second part of the result of the split?  I have

```
line.split(/(?<=#{Regexp.escape(split_token)})/)
```

But the token is getting merged into the first part of teh split and I want it in the second part

```
2.4.0 :004 >   split_token = "aaa"
 => "aaa"
2.4.0 :005 > line = "bbb aaa ccc"
 => "bbb aaa ccc"
2.4.0 :006 > line.split(/(?<=#{Regexp.escape(split_token)})/)
 => ["bbb aaa", " ccc"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing lookbehind (`(?<=`) to lookahead (`(?=`) seems to do the trick:

```
split_token = "aaa"
line = "bbb aaa ccc"
line.split(/(?=#{Regexp.escape(split_token)})/)
# => ["bbb ", "aaa ccc"]
```

This just changes the split point to before the token rather than after it.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use `slice_before` :

```
line.split.slice_before('aaa').map{|s| s.join(' ')}
```